# Css is not working with my html code

Tags: html

I am new to html and css please tell me where I am going wrong

```
    .property1
    {
     color: #0dc3ff;
    }

   <a class="navbar" href="#">Text1<span id ="property1"> + </span> Text2</a>
```

Comment: An ID is not a class.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/azc4rjs3/ Use `#` to select elements by their ids instead of `.`

Comment: use class= "property1" or #property1{color:#0dc3ff}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the following code is doing a property of css on span is what I believe, so .property1 is not a id so you need to call it by span class like below. Remember if you need to call it by ID then you need to use #property1 not .property1

```
     .property1
     {
     color: #0dc3ff;
     }
    <a class="navbar" href="#">Text1<span class ="property1"> + </span> Text2</a>
```

Comment: Remeber calling by class is (.) and calling by ID is #